# Sherlock's String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Question Desc: Sherlock considers a string to be valid if all characters of the string appear the same number of times. It is also valid if he can remove just 1 character at 1 index in the string, and the remaining characters will occur the same number of times. Given a string s, determine if it is valid. If so, return YES, otherwise return NO.

```
def isValid(s):
lst = []
temp = []

for i in s:
    y = i
    lst.append(y)
st = set(lst)

for j in st:
    count = s.count(j)
    temp.append(count)


temp.sort()
print(temp)
b=temp[-1]-temp[-2]
ele = temp[0]
chk=True
for item in temp:
    if ele!=item:
        chk=False;
        break;
    if(chk==True):
        print('YES')
        break;
    elif(b==1):
        print('YES')
        break;
    else:
        print('NO')
        break;
```

For some reason , irrespective of my input , the answer seems to be YES. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

[Link to the question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-valid-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=strings)
PS - You don't need an account to view the question , just click anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the initial values you've set for your variables. On the very first step of your iteration through `temp` you'll find that `ele == item` (because both are `temp[0]`), and then subsequently that `chk == True` (because you set it so). After the first step it'll print yes and break immediately.

Comment: Oh , got it , can you suggest changes too ?